# Lightbox uncentered & missing thumbnail on Chrome

Tags: jquery, css, slider, lightbox

I been google and trying to find a fix as to why the lightbox/carousel for Blogger when I add more than 2 images. The lightbox distorts the alignment, photo uncenter & the carousel thumbnails disappear. It works on Firefox and Safari.

I have a basic understanding of CSS, html, & so forth. Please excuse me if I paste the wrong code. Am still learning as I go.

http://m.tresmuseelle.com/p/blog-page.html

*****UPDATE

I think I found a fix sometimes it work sometimes it doesn't. Sorry for all the error previously

```
.css.lightbox.window.SIG.EXT_hzimg.hzDownscaled {
    display: -ms-flexbox;
    display: -webkit-flex;
    display: flex;

    -ms-flex-align: center;
    -webkit-align-items: center;
    -webkit-box-align: center;

    align-items: center;
}
```

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.blogger.com/static/v1/jsbin/4073657148-lbx.js"></script>


<div id="hzImg" style="border: 1px solid rgb(227, 227, 227); line-height: 0; overflow: hidden; padding: 2px; margin: 0px; position: absolute; z-index: 2147483647; border-radius: 3px; background: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0% 0%, 100% 100%, from(rgb(255, 255, 255)), color-stop(0.5, rgb(255, 255, 255)), to(rgb(237, 237, 237))); box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.46) 3px 3px 6px; opacity: 1; top: 299px; left: 172px; cursor: pointer; display: none;"></div>

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the help page and take a tour of the forumn to see how to ask a question. You post should contain the following: offending code (no links to page) and clear question as to what the issue is.

Comment: @Syfer Hi!!! I tried my best to ask it as clear as I can. I did post the code but not sure what I did. Please excuse my novice skill. :x I did remove the webpage. I apologize!

Answer (score -1):

please disable blogspot default css by adding b:css='false' on `<html> <html/>` tag try it !